# 2D Sprite rotating upside down when coming from right of player C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, artificial-intelligence, sprite

Creating a wave based 2d game and this is my current ai script. It works fine other than that whenever the enemy is coming from the right of the player the sprite is rotated upside down and I cant figure out how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour{
public Transform target;
public int moveSpeed;
public int rotationSpeed;

private Transform myTransform;

// Use this for initialization
void Awake()
{
    myTransform = transform;
}

void Start()
{
    GameObject go = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");

    target = go.transform;


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    GameObject go = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    if  (go != null && target != null)
    {



        Vector3 dir = target.position - myTransform.position;
        dir.z = 0.0f; // Only needed if objects don't share 'z' value

        if (dir != Vector3.zero)
        {
            myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation,

Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.right, dir), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            this.enabled = false;
        }


        //Move Towards Target
        myTransform.position += (target.position - 
        myTransform.position).normalized * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you don't need the y axis you can just freeze that axis on player

Comment: Sadly I do need the y axis.

Comment: By the way, `target` is never going to be null. It's defined as `go.transform` in `Start()`, which if `go` isn't null, also won't be null (and if `go` was null then, it would throw a NPE). Then you never use the `GameObject go` in `Update()` at all.